# Making an added element draggable

Tags: html

I am working with an icon which is clickable and once you clicked it. It will add another icon in the div i want to set the created icon to be draggable and from the inspect element it is draggable yet I can't drag it on my screen. Can someone check what seems to be the problem?

HTML:

```
<div id = icon>
<img class="icon" src="../../Pictures/bulb.png" width="50" height="50"/>
<img class="icon" src="../../Pictures/snow.png" width="50" height="50"/>
</div>
```

Jscript

```
$(function () {
 $('.icon').click(function () { DrawImage($(this).attr('src')); });
});
function DrawImage(a) {
    image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('class', 'drag');
    image.setAttribute('src', a);
    image.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    image.setAttribute('style', 'position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;');
    image.height = 50;
    image.width = 50;
    $('#icon').append(image);
}
```

added this on my html head

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")"></script>
```

update:

fixed it by cloning the image element and assigning some attribute to it

```
var iconnew = $(iconimg).clone();
iconnew.attr({ "id": "clone"});
iconnew.css({'top':mouseY, 'left':mouseX})
iconnew.appendTo('#drag').draggable({ containment: '#bg' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are actually enabling the draggable functionality on your image element when you append it to the DOM. You could try changing your DrawImage function to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qDZsb/